# How to add CORS headers to a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, cors

How it is possible to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to all responses (in particular, I am interested for static files under `/public/`) in Meteor? I would need this so that external web apps can access data provides by my Meteor app. More information about enabling CORS [is here](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

Comment: I think it's impossible in the current state of the Meteor core. We definitly needs a ways to customize `HTTP` headers.

Comment: Is there even not a hackish way? If I would want to use a fork of Meteor, what should I change for this?

Comment: I would suggest Thomas' answer is the correct one, now. Clean way to access connect middleware without third party package / hack.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a little snippet I wrote. You can use as an example in how to access meteor's core connect and modify headers, also a pretty good drop-in for every meteor project:

```js
/**
 * HTTP Header Security
 *
 * enforce HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to prevent ManInTheMiddle-attacks
 * on supported browsers (all but IE)
 * > http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/transport-layer-security
 *
 * @header Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains
 */

var connectHandler = WebApp.connectHandlers; // get meteor-core's connect-implementation

// attach connect-style middleware for response header injection
Meteor.startup(function () {
  connectHandler.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains'); // 2592000s / 30 days
    return next();
  })
})
```

Comment: With the latest version of Meteor (0.8.2) you can use the `WebApp.rawConnectHandlers` "hook", see https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync/blob/master/timesync-server.js

Comment: *Where* do I put this?

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to go about this. One is to modify the meteor code and add it in (so that every file will be have this header). This might not be a great idea because you dont want every single file to have this. But if you do alter up do it with hooking into app

```
var app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app;
app.use(function(req,res) {
    res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
});
```

The other is to use a custom route with something like [meteor router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). This way you can control what files you want to have the headers in so its probably best to use something like this

*Server side js:*

```
Meteor.Router.add('/yourfile.txt', function() {
    this.response.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');

    var fs = Npm.require("fs");
    return fs.readFileSync("/public/yourfile.txt", "utf8");

});
```

Comment: Akshat, could readFileSync have been used in this case to cut down on code?

Comment: @akshat point of clarification... are you talking about making an edit in the meteor core?  somewhere around:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/tools/server/server.js#L297
?

Comment: this can be used in your projects code as long as it runs on the server

Comment: I have tried to make the `app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app;` method work on `server/app.js` (a new file created for this purpose), but I have not been able to get it working.  I'm on `0.6.3`. Any chance you have an example out somewhere?

Comment: `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` has been renamed, and I think the new form to use is `WebApp.connectHandlers`, but you also need to add the WebApp package (with `meteor add webapp`).