# Generate ical file with Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, icalendar

Is there some workaround to generate ical files from meteor (javascript)?.

I've have found this https://github.com/sebbo2002/ical-generator but I don't know how to use it into a Meteor project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have npm package installed, you can use it with `Npm.require`:

```
var ical = Npm.require('ical-generator')
```

Previously it was done with `__meteor_bootstrap__`, but it's outdated.

However, this will only work if you have `ical-generator` installed properly, and would require installing it manually every time you share project with someone. A better solution is to set a dependency in package.

To do so, create `/packages/ical` folder and `/packages/ical/package.js` file with the following content:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Write something meaningful here"
});

Npm.depends({'ical-generator': '0.1.1'});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you need to install npm module:

[To install an npm module in a Meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691513/it-possible-use-a-nodejs-package-inside-meteor-app) :

- **cd .meteor/local/build/server**
- **npm install ical-generator**

Then use it:

```
var ical = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('ical-generator');

cal = ical();

cal.setDomain('example.com');

cal.addEvent({
    start: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600000),
    end: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 7200000),
    summary: 'Example Event',
    description: 'It works ;)',
    organizer: {
        name: 'Organizer\'s Name',
        email: 'organizer@example.com'
    },
    url: 'http://sebbo.net/'
});

console.log(cal.toString());
```

In case you would like to serve iCal file via http with **cal.serve(res)** method you have 2 ways to go, both are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959501/how-to-add-cors-headers-to-a-meteor-app?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: This is outdated, you no longer use `__meteor_bootstrap__.require`. Also, this will require to manually install `ical-generator` after every installation of the project, it won't fetch it automatically as it should. ALSO, I'm not convinced that `.meteor` is a good place for manually installing npm packages.