# Explicit HTTP Response Headers for files in Meteor's public directory

Tags: meteor

I'd like to set custom HTTP Response Headers on files served from the `public` folder in my Meteor app.

WebApp.connectHandlers.use [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959501/how-to-add-cors-headers-to-a-meteor-app) does not affect headers on the on replies to get requests within the public folder (in Meteor 0.8.1.3)

Are custom headers possible for requests to the public folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `WebApp.rawConnectHandlers`; they get run before the Meteor connect handler that serves the static assets. (See packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:259)