# Deleted public folder but is sent to browser

Tags: meteor, public-folders

I'm using meteor to build an app. I had a public folder containing javascript and html files for "tinymce" package. later i didn't use the package so i deleted the folder. Yet when I run my app, the browser shows an error in one of the files in the public folder - which i deleted. Is there something that I did wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't the client receive new versions of this script in the public folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573129/why-wont-the-client-receive-new-versions-of-this-script-in-the-public-folder)

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely due to caching. I've run into similar problems in the past (with images not updating). Only solution I've come by was stopping the meteor process (control + c), purging the browser cache, restarting terminal and my browser, and re-running Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to two parts. The first was caching, and the second was due to a script tag referring to the file - which I forgot to remove - in the head of the layout.