# Web Worker: How to prevent that file gets loaded from cache?

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, web-worker

This is incredibly annoying.. I am wondering why the heck my changes aren't reflected as I notice that my JavaScript file for my Web Worker always gets loaded from cache:

[image]

I have disabled the Cache and hitting `Ctrl + F5` does not work either.

How can I make sure that this file **does not** get loaded from cache?

```
_worker = new Worker('js/toy-cpu.js');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't the client receive new versions of this script in the public folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573129/why-wont-the-client-receive-new-versions-of-this-script-in-the-public-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a kind of version number, for example like this:

```
_worker = new Worker('js/toy-cpu.js?v=' + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: Okay, that would be my last solution if there is no other way to do it since it is surely faster than deleting the cache manually all the time. But I'd still would want my browser to *not* use the cache here. I think I'm not looking for the programmatic solution for a way out but if it can't be helped..

Comment: Then you get into browser-specific areas which cannot be controlled from within Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the purposes of development / the configuration of your personal machine.. rather than that every user needs it to load from the web server.

Chrome has an option to disable cache

[image]

Notice the checkbox "disable cache" that you can check as I have.

And in the section below, where it says "Perform a request". if you refresh then you see the page listed, and it can indicate whether a URL is loaded from the web server, if chrome says 200 and if in the size column it gives size as a number, then it loaded from the web server. And if you double click a URL in the inspector, you see HTTP Headers.